# cambiar de color muchos Jbutton al iniciar la interfaz

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa de reservas y tengo que cambiar de color unos botones dependiendo de cuantas plazas tiene el paquete.
Tengo un inicio de 60 botones y dependiendo de las plazas se pintan x numero de botones

Comment: Hola , Bienvenido a la comunidad, te invito a recorrer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad y sobre todo puedan darte una respuesta favorable.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor Santiago, realiza el [tour] para que entiendas el funcionamiento del sitio, modifica tu pregunta de acuerdo a [ask], saludos!